# is there's possible to convert date obj to another format by helping of MomentJs?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

i've using  package that return date in obj form like

```
 {day: 9, month: 12, year: 2020}
```

i want to use MomentJs to return

```
Sat Dec 19 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
```

i've tried

```
 console.log(moment(calendarDates).format('MMMM Do YYYY'))
```

but i got error i don't know Moment what should expect date form to make the conversion

**

```
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments: 
[0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: [object Object], _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]
```

**

Comment: what is inside the variable `calendarDates`?

Comment: js Date object i believe 
{day: 9, month: 12, year: 2020}

Comment: seems like there is an issue with your `calendarDates` variable because if you use js Date object, this should work correctly

Comment: I think you've to use the `moment-timezone` get the time zone in the output, but except that you can get the date by converting the date object into a string and then pass that string to `moment`, to format and get the result like, `Wed Dec 9 2020`

Comment: my var calendarDates  working fine i can cosleLog it and see it's value but i think the probleme is with Moment js conersion i'ts maby doesn't accepting objects

Comment: No need for MomentJS here ([Moment agrees](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)), you can simply use a js Date `new Date(calendarDate.year, calendarDate.month, calendarDate.day).toString()` or see [Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) for language/timezone formatting.

Comment: thank u @plichard it's worked mate 
and thank u all i love this community